# Error : Parameter is not valid while retrieve image from sql DB

Tags: c#, sql

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select img from image where title = '1' ", con);
    try
    {
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            byte[] img_arr1 = (byte[])dr["img"];
            MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream(img_arr1);                       
            image1.Image = Image.FromStream(m);
        }             
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Error:

> "Parameter is not valid" while retrieve image from sql DB using
>   Windows Application.

Comment: Check the byte you get in img_arr1 ..!! also show the code for saving the image in DB, are you sure that you have saved streamData(byte) from image to DB ?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem might be from your insert statement. I had a similar issue, it will insert but will never retrieve, with an error message "Parameter not Valid".

Try to Use Parameterized Queries while Inserting

Like this

```
scom.CommandText = "insert into Quest ( [TopicT_Id], [Quest], [Image1] ) values (  '" + Guid.NewGuid() + "', '" + quest + "', @image)";
scom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", imagebyte);
```

Instead of

```
scom.CommandText = "insert into Quest ( [TopicT_Id], [Quest], [Image1] ) values (  '" + Guid.NewGuid() + "', '" + quest + "','"+imagebyte+"')";
```

I realised that while inserting the image without using parameters, the Image Values which are forced between ' ' all turns to varchar or other string formats.